# Does Azure Cloud Service Publishing Profile Exists?

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I need to assign publish permission to one of my developers so that he should be able to publish to only one cloud service & do not affect others.

> Azure websites have these concepts called download publishing profile.
>   I could not find anything similar for cloud service. Can it be
>   achieved?

As you know Azure Management Portal does not have any role defined where we could map a user account login to manage a set of resources (say cloud service 1 & 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible as of today. It seems that it should be possible with `Resource Groups` and `Role Based Access Control (RBAC)` however currently cloud services can't be added in resource groups and assigned RBAC.

One way you could achieve this is have a custom application consuming Service Management API and implement your own RBAC in that application. However it is still a "hack" and not proper solution.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, can you think of any other work around to achieve this?

Comment: Updated my answer. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try using "publish from source control"? When the developer checks in it will auto publish the code.

I believe the new portal will allow the creation of roles for publishing profiles; it already allows adding additional users to your organization; but to get what you want for now; publishing from source code should do the trick.